# Can the method defined in source file be inlined?

Tags: c++, inline

For example

```
// a.h
strcut A
{
    void simpleMethod();
    void anotherMethod() {...; simpleMethod(); ...;}
};

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
void A::simpleMethod() { one_line_simple_implementation; }
```

My question is: Can `simpleMethod()` be inlined in `anotherMethod()` by the modern compiler optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, yes. if `a.cpp` includes `a.h` (I suppose so). As long as the compiler can see the full definition. it is fine. But you need to say so.

```
inline     void A::simpleMethod() { one_line_simple_implementation; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `inline void A::simpleMethod() { ... }` or you might get multiple definitions error if you don't use `inline` keyword.
or you could just do

```
class A
{
    void foo() { ... };
};
```